# Puzzle: How many ways can a chain of length $n$ be "cracked" to form new smaller chains?

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science, puzzle

**Background:**

This is a chemistry inspired problem. Alkanes are simply chains of carbon with hydrogens attached to each carbon (the general formula is $C_n H_{2n+2}$).

Alkenes are chains of carbon similar to alkanes, although they have a double bond and have the general formula $C_n H_{2n}$

Alkanes can be cracked to produce alkanes and alkenes. Cracking involves breaking a bond betweek two carbon atoms. In each "crack," only one bond in the chain can be broken. For each "crack," one alkene and one alkane is produced.

[image]

---

**Puzzle:**

Given that the smallest possible alkene contains chain length two, and given that the alkane produced from cracking a larger alkane can also be cracked, how many ways can an alkane of chain length $n$ be cracked so that the orginal chain is cracked at least one time.

---

**Steps towards a solution:**

As far as I am concerned, the hydrogen is not relevant; so we are trying to work out how to split a chain so that one part of it can be split again. My best idea so far was to use an algorithm almost identical to the [change making algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) to work out how many combinations of $1, 2, 3... n$ length chains there are that create a $n$ length chain

**Edit:**

Another way I think this can be thought about is how many ways can a chain of length nn be broken so that all but 1 or less constituent chains has a length of two or greater. I believe that only one methane molecule could be produced as producing an methane molecule is the final possible crack in any sequence seeing as the other part must be an alkene so it is impossible to crack further.

Comment: Does order matter? Is cracking octane into (2, 2, 4) the same as cracking it into (2, 4, 2)?

Comment: @PeterKagey let's say order doesn't matter, so different permutations of the same combination are allowed

Comment: Also, we're not allowed to crack propane into a butane and methane, right?

Comment: three points: Can we crack to methane? And, related, does the double-bond go preferentially to one side or the other (eg smaller molecule)? And if we have a double bond on the end of a chain, can we crack ethene off that leaving another double bond on the remaining chain?

Comment: @Joffan 1) We can crack to methane - for example the only possible way to crack propane would be to create methane and ethene because the smallest alkene possible is ethene. 2) Let's say there's no preference in where the double bond goes. 3) This is a point I struggled with for a while, I wanted the puzzle to be as true to actual events as possible, but judging by the lack of information returned when I searched for whether "alkenes can be cracked," I am going to say no to that possibility. But it would be interesting to see how that changes the result

Comment: @Ronikos If I understand correctly, you are trying to count the number of partitions of $n$ into parts of size $>1$.  The generating function for this is $(1-x)$ times the regular GF for partitions, so it should be equal to $p(n)-p(n-1)$.  For example when $n=8$ this gives $22-15 = 7$ partitions (including the null case where we don't crack at all).  Does this agree with your findings?

Comment: @Ronikos If you can crack to methane, can octane be cracked into 8 methanes?  No limits whatsoever?  Then you are dealing with a standard partition function.

Comment: @ErickWong For each crack, an alkene must also be produce. So octane could be cracked into hexane and ethene, then the hexane could be cracked into ethene and butant, then the butane could be cracked into propene and methane. So one combination could be 2 ethenes, 1 propene and 1 methane

Comment: @ErickWong Another way I think this can be thought about is how many ways can a chain of length $n$ be broken so that all but 1 or less constituent chains has a length of two or greater. I believe that only one methane molecule could be produced as producing an methane molecule is the final possible crack in any sequence seeing as the other part must be an alkene so it is impossible to crack further.

Comment: @PeterKagey I've edit the question with a potential alternative way to go about the question

Comment: @Joffan I've edit the question with a potential alternative way to go about the question

Comment: @Ronikos My previous comment answers the "length two or greater" version: $f(n) = p(n)-p(n-1)$.  To incorporate the option of having a single length-1 chain, we just need to add $f(n-1)$, so the final answer would be $f(n) + f(n-1) = p(n)-p(n-2)$, possibly less $1$ if you require at least one crack.  For $n=7$ this gives $15-7 = 8$ possibilities.  Does this match your observations?

Comment: The $8$ combinations for $n=7$ correspond to: 7, 5-2, 4-3, 3-2-2, 6-1, 4-2-1, 3-3-1, 2-2-2-1.  If all of these are actually possible then your characterization makes sense and I believe this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In its current form, the question asks how many distinct ways there are to divide the number $n$ into one or more values that are $\ge 2$, with possibly one exceptional value of $1$.  Here is the answer to that specific question:

Let $f(n)$ be the numbers of ways to partition $n$ into values $\ge 2$, where the order of the values within a given partition does not matter (only the number of occurrences of each value).  Then the generating function $\sum_{n\ge 0} f(n) x^n$ is given by the formal product

$$\prod_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{1-x^k} = \prod_{k=2}^\infty (1+x^k+x^{2k}+x^{3k}+\cdots).$$

Comparing this to the very similar g.f. for the standard [partition function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) we see that $$\sum_{n\ge 0} f(n) x^n = (1-x) \sum_{n\ge 0} p(n) x^n = \sum_{n\ge 0} (p(n) - p(n-1))x^n,$$

so that $f(n) = p(n)-p(n-1)$ for $n\ge 1$.  Finally the number of partitions of $n$ with exactly one part of size $1$ is the same as $f(n-1)$ from the remaining chain of length $n-1$.  Therefore the answer to the question posed at the top of this answer is $f(n) + f(n-1) = p(n) - p(n-2)$, valid for $n\ge 2$.  If we wish to exclude the trivial partition ($n$ itself) then subtract $1$ from this.

For example, when $n=7$, $p(7) = 15$, $p(6) = 11$ and $p(5) = 7$, so we expect there to be $4$ partitions with all parts $\ge 2$ and $4$ partitions with exactly one part $=1$.  These are indeed given by:

```
7,   5-2,   4-3,   3-2-2,
6-1, 4-2-1, 3-3-1, 2-2-2-1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer, how would this change if two different permutations of the same pathway to the same final products were counted differently. For example, `8ane to 5ane, 3ene to 3ane, 2ene, 3ene` was different to `8ane to 6ane, 2ene to 3ane, 3ene, 2ene` ie. non distinct ways. Would it simply be $p(n)$?

Comment: @Ronikos No, the answer would be radically different: it would be at least $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor!$ since if we choose to break at only even-numbered positions then it is always possible, and we could do it in any order.  This is a much faster-growing function than $p(n)$: for large $n$, the number of digits in $(n/2)!$ is $O(n \log n)$, while the number of digits in $p(n)$ is $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: @Ronikos It's a little unclear from your sequence whether you are saying the order of the *cracks* matters, or just the order of where the end products fit in the original chain.  If the latter, then you will have something like a Fibonacci-like growth, which has $O(n)$ digits, again much larger than $O(\sqrt{n})$.

Comment: I meant the former, say the order of the cracks mattered?

Comment: @Ronikos Maybe it isn't quite factorial because we are constrained to only be able to crack the alkane, so essentially when we have $m$ products we could at each stage decide to crack either the left end piece or the right, inflating the count by a factor of $2^m$.  I believe this would be $O(n)$ digits as well.  In any case the variant you are asking is a very different question and probably deserves a separate question post.